# Proof that Householder Triangularization for QR is backward stable

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

How do you prove that QR factorization via Householder Triangularization is backward stable?

**Theorem 16.1** (From Trefethen and Bau): Let the $QR$ factorization of a matrix $A$ be computed by Householder triangularization on a computer satisfying the floating point arithmetic axioms. Let the $\tilde{Q}$ and $\tilde{R}$ be the computed factors. Then we have
$$\tilde{Q}\tilde{R} = A + \delta A$$ 
and 
$$\frac{||{\delta A}||}{||A||} = O(\epsilon_{machine})$$

Comment: If $H$ is an elementary Householder transformation and $\tilde H$ is its computed counterpart, then $\|H-\tilde{H}\|_2=O(\epsilon)$ and $\mathrm{fl}(\tilde{H}A)=H(A+E)$, where $\|E\|_2=O(\epsilon\|A\|_2)$.

Comment: There must be something obvious that I'm not seeing. Why is the first statement $|| H - \tilde{H}||_2 = O(\epsilon)$ true?

Comment: The proofs are not hard but very technical. You can find more details in Section 18.3 of [this book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=5tv3HdF-0N8C). This result is actually not very interesting and is true for all orthogonalization algorithms (even for the classical Gram-Schmidt). You can deduce it from Lemma 18.3 in the linked book. What is actually more pleasant for the Householder algorithm is that the "computed" $Q$ is really close to the exact $Q$ (see Theorem 18.4 there).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will go take a look at the book.